# System doesn't boot due to a "[drm: drm_crtc_helper_set_config] * error * "

Tags: 12.10, boot

I have a problem with the new Ubuntu 12.10. It finished installing correctly, but when I restart my computer an error message appears:

```
[15.854296] [drm: drm_crtc_helper_set_config] * error * failed to set mode on [CRTC: 10]
* checking battery state
[17.814209] [drm: drm_crtc_helper_set_config] * error * failed to set mode on [CRTC: 10]
```

and that screen does not advance.

I also tried booting from the recovery mode and it starts, but it's too slow loading windows and also shows me a window with an error message:

> Sorry Ubuntu 12.10 has experienced an internal error 
>   More Details: Executable path /usr/bin/xorg

I have used Ubuntu since the 2008 version and never had this problem.

I hope you can help me.

**Computer Specs:**

> compaq sr2015la 
>   AMD sempron 
>   2Gb. RAM 
>   80Gb Hard Drive

[Translated from the original Spanish](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/205493/1)

Comment: well, "es demasiado lento al cargar las ventanas" means "it's too slow loading **the** windows", he meant the ubuntu windows, not the windows OS.

Comment: @EvandroSilva My apologies. My knowledge of Russian and Vietnamese doesn't really help me here :)

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue using 12.10 on a Lenovo ThinkPad T430 on a docking station. The analog monitor works fine, but when the DVI-D monitor is attached, the drm error occurs. Remove the DVI cable, and the system boots again (although I need to `dpkg-reconfigure gdm` to reset the display manager)